# Importar csv como float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou importando uma base para o python, porem não consigo manipula-lo(fazer média), por o mesmo esta como str, necessito que ao importa-lo todos os valores venham como float.

```
data=pd.read_csv('C:\\caminho\\df.csv', index_col=0, dtype=np.float64)
```

utilizei a seguinte sintaxe para importa,
ele me mostra um erro na ultima coluna, dizendo que não pode converter, poderiam me ajudar? 
já tentei ate transformar o data frame depois de importado ulilizando 
`np.float64(data)`, porem o mesmo vira array, ai todas as funções deixam de funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,
Amigo ao analisar seu comando ele está correto, o seu problema pode ser no seu arquivo `.csv`, o pandas infere o `dtype` automaticamente baseado no conteúdo importado, embora grande parte do conteúdo do seu csv seja numérico se existe uma única linha com valores em string, seu dataframe irá assumir o **dtype string**. Para resolver este problema basta remover a linha correspondente.

Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que estes *str* podem ser convertidos em *float*, podes usar o pd.to_numeric():

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1.', '2.'], ['3.', '4.']])
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar o método [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) passando o parâmetro `errors` da seguinte forma:

```
df['suaColuna'] = pd.to_numeric(df['suaColuna'], errors='coerce')

// errors = 'coerce' -> se tiver um valor inválido ele vai virar NaN
```